# Getting table header and body to match column widths

Tags: html, css

I created the following [CodePen Source](https://codepen.io/adviner/pen/KKZvePb?editors=1100)

The following CSS works great in getting the body to scroll properly but the header and body don't line up.

[image]

The table structure is as follows:

```
<div>
    <table class="is-table-with-scrolling-body">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Created By</th>
             <th>Subject</th>
             <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>File</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr data-index="0">
             <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
             <td>First upload of...</td>
             <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
             <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          ...
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the CSS that makes the body scrollable (found online from my research) is:

```
table {
  &.is-table-with-scrolling-body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

    thead,
    tbody,
    tr {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      > th {
        border: solid 1px red;
      }
    }

    tbody {
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
      table-layout: fixed;
      max-height: 190px;;
      > tr {
        > td {
          border: solid 1px red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include enough code necessary to produce a [example]. I cannot replicate your issue with this code.

Comment: I added the CodePen link above under "CodePen" that includes the whole source

Comment: I updated it to say "CodePen Source"

Comment: Mine looks like the screenshot where the header columns and body columns are not lining up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your SCSS to CSS

You need to hide the right edge scrollbar while keeping the functionality
which means styling using

`::webkit-scrollbar`

or similar as your needs require

> ```
> table.is-table-with-scrolling-body thead::-webkit-scrollbar,
> table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
>   display: none;
> }
> ```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body thead,
table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody {
  overflow: auto;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body thead::-webkit-scrollbar,
table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body thead tr,
table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body thead tr>th,
table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody tr>th {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody {
  display: block;
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-height: 200px;
}

table.is-table-with-scrolling-body tbody>tr>td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="is-table-with-scrolling-body">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="0">
        <td><span>Person Name 1</span></td>
        <td>First upload of...</td>
        <td>3/21/2022 7:18 PM</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice, let me give that a try and it seems like its supported by most browsers

Comment: It works for everything but Firefox, but found a solution by adding 
scrollbar-width: none; to tbody also.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, that makes sense FF is not a -webkit- browser, if anything it'd be -moz-  but it looks like they've added that styling without the need for the prefix.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Thanks

Comment: This is not a valid solution since the headers are also scrolling with the body.  Users want to continue to see the headers as they scroll.  It surprises me how hard this is.  It is even hard when you throw in bootstrap.

Comment: @plex4r: which browser are you using? When I run the snippet from Chrome the headers  remain in place while scrolling. And, as mentioned, this is likely not compatible with non -webkit- browsers, but there may be work arounds.